# Should my company assume the cost of applying for the OPT STEM Extension?

Tags: startup, legal, visa, expenses

To contextualize better the situation, I work in a San Francisco startup of 5 employees, which is in the process of getting a series A funding round, and had a previous seed round of around 3 million $.

As a foreigner under an F-1 visa, after one year of  working you need to renew your work permission (a procedure called OPT STEM Extension) and the USCIS charges approximately 400$ for just processing the application.

Is there any general tendency, in companies similar to the profile described above, on which part does assume this cost?

Comment: Have you asked your boss how this should be handled on *your* company?

Comment: The whole purpose of the question is to have an idea of the general norm in similar companies to decide asking him or not for a reimbursement

Comment: There generally isn't much risk in asking your company about whether or not they'll reimburse some expense required for you to do or continue doing your job. If they're not willing to, the worst that will happen is they'll say no.

Comment: @DarkCygnus I guess if you don't want indirect questions, don't give indirect answers. Thanks for the feedback anyway

Comment: @ArnoldFrenzy no problem, I see you accepted an answer so it seems you sorted this out :) Although I see you only got one, perhaps because of what I mentioned in the previous comment. Good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is company specific.  Some don’t have a specific policy either.  Your best bet is to review your work manual/guide/handbook and ask your manager.